# Getting no response after sending a Guzzle http request from within a job

Tags: laravel

Im sending off a a payload to a service to print a pdf right from within a laravel job. I am running the job locally using `artisan queue:work database` and `handle()` does get invoked up until the part where I send a http request using Guzzle.

```
handle() {

    try {

        print_r("Assembling invoice data\n");

        // ...
        // ... doing some manual serialising
        // ...

        $client = new Client();
        print_r("Sending pdf print job\n");
        $response = $client->request("POST", $url, [
            "json" => [
                "sender_info" => $senderInfo,
                "contact" => $contact,
                "invoice_lines" => $invoiceLines,
                "invoice_totals" => $invoiceTotals,
                "invoice_footer" => $this->invoice->footer,
                "invoice_note" => $this->invoice->note,
                "invoice_meta" => [
                    "key" => $this->invoice->meta_key,
                    "value" => $this->invoice->meta_value
                ],
                "invoice_date" => $this->invoice->date->format("d-m-Y"),
                "invoice_due_date" => $this->invoice->due_date->format("d-m-Y"),
                "invoice_color" => $this->invoice->color,
                "invoice_number" => $this->invoice->number_prefix . $this->invoice->number_value,
                "logo" => $this->invoice->logo,
                "id" => $this->invoice->id
            ]
        ]);
        print_r($response);

        if ($response->getStatusCode() !== 200) {
            print_r("pdf print job failed\n");

            // @todo: send message to bugsnagger
            throw new \Exception("Generating a pdf failed");
        }

        print_r("Pdf print job complete\n");

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e);
    }
}
```

I verified that the job is running up to the client request, but not after by reading the `print_r()` statements. When the job is executed, all I get to see is;

```
[2018-07-01 09:04:36] Processing: App\Jobs\ProcessNewInvoice
Assembling invoice data
Sending pdf print job
```

... 255 times in just a second.

I had this code running outside of a Laravel job at first. That seemed to work. Not timeouts or such. Now I am having trouble figuring it out where it fails. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The cause was quite unrelated.

```
"invoice_date" => $this->invoice->date->format("d-m-Y"),
"invoice_due_date" => $this->invoice->due_date->format("d-m-Y"),
```

The date properties on the model were not converted to a Carbon object and therefor the `->format()` method didn't exist. To fix the date conversion on my model I had to add these to Invoice.php;

```
protected $dates = [
    "date",
    "due_date",
];
```

It still bugs me that the job didnt throw an exception and it did not get marked as failed.